Should we wait for LTS first point release (e.g. 24.04.1) to upgrade from interim version (e.g. 23.10)?
I often read it is better to wait until the first point of the LTS version of Ubuntu (e.g. 24.04.1) is released before upgrading. Does it also applies to upgrades from interim version (e.g. 23.10)? More especially if the interim version reached is End-of-Life (EOL)?

Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

The upgrade from Ubuntu 23.10 to 24.04 reached stable some time ago, and due to 23.10 no longer receiving security fixes (it's EOL) there no longer is any CI/QA performed on the upgrade cycle, and it's getting less stable as 24.04 continues to advance. The upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 is still not deemed stable, but you're not asking about that; the upgrade to 23.10 was stable, but you've actually missed that due to EOL already.  Your release isn't on-topic here any longer.

Your question is too subjective to answer without being just an opinion based one. However, that said, I would be tempted to create a live USB of 24.04 and use that as your daily driver to test it out in order to ensure it meets your needs. Not long to go anyway till the first point release drops.

You are asking for opinion-based answers based upon a false premise that @guiverc has well explained. Two reasons to close the question.

Based on your comments, my understanding is that "waiting for a .1 LTS version" is a piece of advice restricted to those that are on an older LTS version. Upgrading to 24.04 should have been done before 23.10 EOL. Then, I guess I should upgrade asap.

Yes; Ubuntu LTS development occurs over a two year period; with the development of 24.04 LTS started just after 22.04 LTS was released.  The progress of that two year development progress could be seen by the interim releases of 22.10, 23.04 & the closest to what the final product was is 23.10, before final release was Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and the conclusion of the two year development cycle.  The upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 is the smallest of those upgrades (22.04->22.10, 22.10->23.04 & 23.04->23.10 are more significant)... though yours is slightly larger now given your delay...

The upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 is a jump from one development cycle to the next; and includes all of what was done in the four upgrades in last comment... why it's more significant & not yet being deemed stable.

This question seems to be server related and concerns upgrade from LTS to LTS. My question is about upgrading from a non-LTS (23.10) to an LTS (24.04). In the comments here, some people think the answer to my question would be "opinion-based" because I'm asking for "advice". I might have chosen the wrong word when saying "advice". What was unclear to me was how stable is an upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 if not waiting for 24.04.1. Answers from @guiverc are very clear and my understanding is that waiting for 24.04.1 is actually not a stable option in this case.

Based on comments below the main post:
Ubuntu LTS development occurs over a two year period; with the development of 24.04 LTS started just after 22.04 LTS was released. The progress of that two year development progress could be seen by the interim releases of 22.10, 23.04 & the closest to what the final product was is 23.10, before final release was Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and the conclusion of the two year development cycle. The upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 is the smallest of those upgrades (22.04->22.10, 22.10->23.04 & 23.04->23.10 are more significant).
The upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 is a jump from one development cycle to the next; and includes all of what was done in the four upgrades in last comment... why it's more significant & not yet being deemed stable.
A stable upgrade from an LTS to the next one is deemed stable when the ".1" version is released (e.g., 24.04.1). However, from an interim version, the upgrade to the next LTS is deemed stable before the release of the ".1" version. What's more, the upgrade won't be considered stable if the interim version reaches it's End-of-Life (EOL).
